# Change color of date of any particular day column?

Tags: php, html

How can I set the day 'Sunday' date column in red color. While using 'colgroup' can change the background color only but how can I change the date color of one column i.e. Sunday. Ex: If we talk aboyut todays date then change the color of date '4','11','18','25' in red color. Please help... Thanks

**CALENDAR.PHP**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a
{
text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   
<h1 style=" margin-left: 608px; color:brown; ">Calendar (PHP)</h1>

<?php
$monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
                     "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"); 
   
if (!isset($_GET["month"]))
{
    $_GET["month"]=date("n");
    }
    
    if (!isset($_GET["year"]))
    {
        $_GET["year"]=date("Y");
    }
    
      
    $current_month=$_GET["month"] ;
    $current_year=$_GET["year"] ;
    
    
    $prevous_month=$current_month-1;
    $next_month=$current_month+1;
    
    $prevous_year=$current_year-1;
    $next1_year=$current_year+1;
    
    
    $prev_year=$current_year;
    $next_year=$current_year;
    
    if( $prevous_month == 0 )
    {
    
        $prevous_month= 12;
        $prev_year=$current_year-1;
    }
    
    if( $next_month == 13 )
    {
    
        $next_month=1;
        $next_Year=$current_year+1;
    }
    
    echo "<table style='margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 586px;'>
       
          
    <tr>
    <td colspan=1 align='center' style='color:pink'><button> <a href=". "?year=" . $prevous_year." ><<</a></button></td>
    
    <td colspan=1 align='center'> <button><a href="."?month=".$prevous_month."&year=".$prev_year."><</a></button></td>
    
    <td colspan=3 align='center'><button > <a href= "."?month=".date('m')."&year=".date('Y').">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Today Date&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button></td>
     
    <td colspan=1 align='center'><button> <a href=". "?month=".$next_month. "&year=" . $next_year.">></a></button></td>
    
    <td colspan=1 align='center'><button> <a href=" ."?year=" . $next1_year.">>></a></button></td>
     
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td colspan=3 align=center style='color:green'>".date('d').", ".$monthNames[$current_month-1].", ". $current_year."</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td align='center' style='color:red'>Sun</td>
    <td align='center' style='color:blue'>Mon</td>
    <td align='center' style='color:blue'>Tue</td>
    <td align='center' style='color:blue'>Wed</td>
    <td align='center' style='color:blue'>Thu</td>
    <td align='center' style='color:blue'>Fri</td>
    <td align='center' style='color:blue'>Sat</td>
    </tr>";
    
    
    
    $time = mktime(0,0,0,$current_month,1,$current_year);
    
    $totle_day = date("t",$time);
    
    $thismonth = getdate ($time);
    
    $startday = $thismonth['wday'];
    
    
    for ($i=0; $i<($totle_day+$startday); $i++)
     {
        
       if(($i % 7) == 0 )
    
             echo "<tr>";
    
       if($i < $startday)
    
            echo "<td></td>";
       
       else 
            
            echo "<td align='center' >". ($i - $startday +1) . "</td>";
    
       if(($i % 7) == 6 )
    
            echo "</tr>";
    }
    
    
    echo "</table>";
    
    
    
    ?>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: check out my `method2` which will be more simpler and can be use to style any nth column in table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

give the first column a class name like `sunday` and give `sunday` class your desired styles.

example

change

```
echo "<td align='center' >". ($i - $startday +1) . "</td>";
```

to

```
if($i % 7 == 0)
   echo "<td align='center' class='sunday'>". ($i - $startday +1) . "</td>";
else
    echo "<td align='center' >". ($i - $startday +1) . "</td>";
```

in css style sheet add this

```
.sunday
{
color:red;
}
```

**Method 2:**

You can make it more simpler by using this.
Give the table an id say `weeks`

and in style sheet add this

```
#weeks td:first-child {color: red; }
```

Comment: Thanx #krishna it's working... i think this one is easiest way... thank u so much...

Comment: hmm Method 2: is more easiest way... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  for ($i=0; $i<($totle_day+$startday); $i++)
     {

       if(($i % 7) == 0 )

             echo "<tr>";

       if($i < $startday)

            echo "<td></td>";

       else if(($i % 7) == 0 )

            echo "<td align='center' style='color:red;' >". ($i - $startday +1) . "</td>";

       else 

        echo "<td align='center' >". ($i - $startday +1) . "</td>";


       if(($i % 7) == 6 )

            echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: You are always welcome mate. :)